# What would be the php equivalent of this unix command

Tags: php, bash, unix

I need to get the difference of two csv files just like this

```
comm -13 <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > file3.csv
```

This works fine but how to achieve the same proces from PHP, some hints to point me in the right direction. (edited)

```
ABC, 12, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 0, 0

ABC, 8, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

The final CSV should be like this :

```
ABC, 8, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

No exec() can be used so how would you deal with this in an efficient way with PHP?

I tried the solution from Marc below:

```
<?php
    $file1 = file('file1.csv');
    $file2 = file('file2.csv');

    sort($file1);
    sort($file2);

    var_dump($file1);
    var_dump($file2);

    $diff =  array_diff($file2, $file1);

    var_dump($diff);

?>
```

returns this

```
ABC, 8, 1
DEF, 10, 1
GHI, 2, 0
```

When I pre-sort them manually it works fine. Yet when I dump the arrays after applying sort they seem sorted?

The problems seems to have been that the last line wasn't followed by a newline character.

```
$file1 = file('file1.csv',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$file2 = file('file2.csv',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

**FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** seems to fix it.

So Marc's solution works great if you add FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES.

Comment: If it's something serious, `exec()` et al. should be disabled for security reasons, IMO.

Comment: So you are not sure yet but ask in advance to get some virtual code that probably never comes to use?

Comment: Yes exec will probably be disabled that's why I ask for a php solution

Comment: Then show your code what you've tried so far. I find it a bit harsh that you ask others to do some work for you while you might not even need this. You did only post some requirements and that's it.

Comment: I'm not really all that familiar with PHP that's why I asked some hints where to start.  I'm not asking others to do some work for me just point me in the right direction to do it in an efficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file1 = file('file1.csv');
$file2 = file('file2.csv');

$sorted1 = sort($file1);
$sorted2 = sort($file2);

/// mangle arrays to remove columns 1,3 here...

$diff = array_diff($mangled1, $mangled2);
file_put_contents('file3.csv', implode($diff));
```

Comment: Isn't file a risk when handling large files?  It's a file with a few thousand lines.

Comment: no different than blindly doing a `file_get_contents`. Either way you're sucking the entire file into memory.

Comment: yes that's what I feared.  What do you mean with mangle arrays to remove columns 1,3 ?